# Java GridBagLayout: Rows are overlapping

Tags: java, swing, overlap, gridbaglayout, overlapping

I have a pretty simple JFrame. There are three main panels: the banner image at the top, a list of buttons on the left-hand side, and the main panel where the user will input his login information to access the rest of the application.

I'm using a GridBagLayout, and despite most people avoiding it like the plague, it's very straightforward to me, though it does add many lines of code into the mix. However I'm getting this strange problem where the top row (banner image) is overlapping the bottom row (button and login panels). I've checked and double-checked and looked all over the web for an answer but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Basically the bottom row is vertically centered in the JFrame as a whole, and not in the second GridBag row as it should. And somehow the BannerPanel is being drawn on top of that, despite being added to the screen beforehand. I think it may have something to do with the way the BannerPanel works but I for one can't find a workaround.

This is what it looks like:

https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc7/375898_3720190211823_1073177291_n.jpg

This is what it SHOULD look like:

https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/314993_3720190291825_1429407717_n.jpg

Here's my code:

```
public class LoginWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    final static String unlockCode = "unlock";
    ArrayList <User> userlist = new ArrayList <User> ();
    User user = null;

    // The visible parts of the window
    GridBagConstraints gridbag;
    JLabel inputLabel, errorLabel, lockedLabel, unlockLabel;
    JTextField usernameField, unlockField;
    JPasswordField passwordField;
    JPanel inputPanel, usernamePanel, passwordPanel, unlockPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoginWindow win = new LoginWindow ();
        win.userlist.add(new User ("username", "password", true));
    }

    public LoginWindow () {
        setTitle("Login");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setSize(640, 480);
        setResizable(false);
        resetGridbag();

        // This is where I declare all the JLabels, JPanels, etc
        inputLabel = new JLabel ("Secure Login");
        inputLabel.setFont(new Font ("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 24));
        inputLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel ("Username  ");
        usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        usernameField = new JTextField (10);
        usernameField.setActionCommand("Login");
        usernameField.addActionListener(this);
        usernamePanel = new JPanel ();
        usernamePanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        usernamePanel.add(usernameLabel);
        usernamePanel.add(usernameField);

        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel ("Password  ");
        passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        passwordField = new JPasswordField (10);
        passwordField.setActionCommand("Login");
        passwordField.addActionListener(this);
        passwordPanel = new JPanel ();
        passwordPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        passwordPanel.add(passwordLabel);
        passwordPanel.add(passwordField);

        errorLabel = new JLabel ("");
        errorLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        lockedLabel = new JLabel ("You've been locked out!");
        lockedLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        unlockLabel = new JLabel ("Unlock Code");
        unlockLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        unlockField = new JTextField (10);
        unlockField.setActionCommand("Unlock");
        unlockField.addActionListener(this);
        unlockPanel = new JPanel ();
        unlockPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        unlockPanel.add(unlockLabel);
        unlockPanel.add(unlockField);

        JLabel newPassword = new JLabel ("Request a new password");
        newPassword.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        JPanel optionPanel = new JPanel ();
        optionPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        optionPanel.add(newPassword);

        inputPanel = new JPanel ();
        inputPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        inputPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout ());

        // Now I'm going to add them all to the screen
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout ();
        gbl.columnWeights = new double [] {0.0f, 1.0f};
        gbl.rowWeights = new double [] {0.0f, 1.0f};
        setLayout(gbl);

        gridbag.gridwidth = 2;
        gridbag.gridy = 0;
        gridbag.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(new BannerPanel (), gridbag);
        gridbag.gridy = 1;
        gridbag.gridwidth = 1;
        gridbag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        add(optionPanel, gridbag);
        gridbag.gridx++;
        gridbag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        add(inputPanel, gridbag);

        redraw();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void resetGridbag () {
        gridbag = new GridBagConstraints ();
        gridbag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gridbag.gridx = gridbag.gridy = 0;
    }

    public void reset () {
        inputPanel.removeAll();
        resetGridbag();
        validate();
        repaint();
    }

    public void redraw () {
        reset();
        if (user == null || !user.locked()) {
            inputPanel.add(inputLabel, gridbag);
            gridbag.gridy++;
            inputPanel.add(new JLabel ("   "), gridbag);
            gridbag.gridy++;
            inputPanel.add(usernamePanel, gridbag);
            gridbag.gridy++;
            inputPanel.add(passwordPanel, gridbag);
            gridbag.gridy++;
            inputPanel.add(new JLabel ("   "), gridbag);
            gridbag.gridy++;
            inputPanel.add(errorLabel, gridbag);
        }
        else {
            inputPanel.add(lockedLabel, gridbag);
            gridbag.gridy++;
            inputPanel.add(unlockPanel, gridbag);
            gridbag.gridy++;
            inputPanel.add(errorLabel, gridbag);
            errorLabel.setText("");
        }
        validate();
        repaint();
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        String button = e.getActionCommand();
        if (button.equals("Login")) {
            boolean usernameMatch = false;
            boolean passwordMatch = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < userlist.size(); i++) {
                if (usernameField.getText().equals(userlist.get(i).username())) {
                    usernameMatch = true;
                    user = userlist.get(i);
                }
                if (new String (passwordField.getPassword()).equals(userlist.get(i).password()))
                    passwordMatch = true;
            }
            passwordField.setText("");

            if (usernameMatch) {
                if (passwordMatch) {
                    user.unlock();
                    //new MainWindow ();
                    dispose();
                }
                else {
                    user.loginFail();
                    if (!user.locked())
                        errorLabel.setText("Login unsuccessful. " +
                                user.loginAttempts() + " attempts left!");
                    else
                        redraw();
                }
            }
            else
                errorLabel.setText("Login unsuccessful.");

            validate();
        }
        else if (button.equals("Unlock")) {
            if (unlockField.getText().equals(unlockCode)) {
                errorLabel.setText("");
                user.unlock();
                redraw();
            }
            else {
                errorLabel.setText("Invalid unlock code.");
                validate();
            }
            unlockField.setText("");
        }
    }
}

class BannerPanel extends JPanel {
    Image image;
    int width = 0, height = 0;
    double ratio = 0.0;

    public BannerPanel () {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(BannerPanel.class
                    .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("banner.png"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        ratio = (double) getWidth() / image.getWidth(null);
        width = getWidth();
        height = getImageHeight();
        setSize(width, height);

        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, this);
        }
    }

    public int getImageHeight () {
        return (int) (image.getHeight(null) * ratio);
    }
}

public class User {
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    boolean superuser = false;
    int loginAttempts = 3;

    public User (String username, String password, boolean superuser) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.superuser = superuser;
    }

    public String username () {
        return username;
    }

    public String password () {
        return password;
    }

    public boolean superuser () {
        return superuser;
    }

    public int loginAttempts () {
        return loginAttempts;
    }

    public void loginFail () {
            if (loginAttempts > 0)
            loginAttempts--;
    }

    public boolean locked () {
        return (loginAttempts == 0);
    }

    public void lock () {
        loginAttempts = 0;
    }

    public void unlock () {
        loginAttempts = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so copied the code to have a look at, but the part that is probably the most important (where you layout the labels and fields) is missing. Oh, and it won't compile :)

Comment: Whoops. I put the rest back in. Should compile now...

Comment: @RichYoung I'm missing the `User` class as well as the `reset` and `revalidate` methods for `LoginWindow`.

Comment: btw: **never-ever** change the state of the component while painting, that is, **do not** call setSize (at best, it does nothing anyway).

Comment: Okay... But if I move setSize() to BannerPanel's constructor, it's drawn with 0 height. So it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

The height of your `BannerPanel` is based on the height of the image (`height = getImageHeight();`). However, this is the height the `BannerPanel` is *drawn* at, not the height it *asks for*. You need to override `getPreferredSize()` to deliver the correct desired height based on the image and ratio - otherwise the layout will be made assuming 0 height for the `BannerPanel`.

### Edit

I think the problem is that you're trying to create a component with a fixed ratio between height and width, while deferring the width to the parent container. This creates a situation where you have to wait for the layout to be performed once before you can know the component's preferred size. Performing these calculations in `paintComponent` will work, as you've experienced, by waiting for layout, resizing, drawing, waiting for layout and drawing again. It's not ideal - you do have to perform the layout twice, but there's no intrinsic need to do the drawing twice. I don't think Swing gives you enough control to reliably avoid this, but there *are* more idiomatic ways to do it! For example, you can override `setBounds` to change the preferred height based on the actual width:

```
@Override
public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    int pWidth = getPreferredSize().width;
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pWidth, width / 2));
}
```

Comment: So I left the lines that set `ratio`, `width` and `height` in `paintComponent()`, took out `setSize()`, and overrode `getPreferredSize()` to return a `Dimension` with the `width` and `height`... no dice. The image is impossibly small at the top...

Comment: In fact, even putting `setSize()` back in `paintComponent()` isn't working, but removing the override makes the image resume its normal size.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob Raihle had the right idea, however it didn't work for me.
What did work was adding a call to `setPreferredSize()` to `paintComponent()`, right next to `setSize()`.

Apparently `setSize()` allows the entire image to be drawn while `setPreferredSize()` tells the rest of the layout how much space it's taking up. Would be great to have it all in one method without having to override but hey, what are you gonna do?

Here's the new code for my BannerPanel object:

```
class BannerPanel extends JPanel {
    Image image;
    int width = 0, height = 0;
    double ratio = 0.0;

    public BannerPanel () {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(BannerPanel.class
                    .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("banner.png"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        ratio = (double) getWidth() / image.getWidth(null);
        width = getWidth();
        height = getImageHeight();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension (width, height));
        setSize(width, height);

        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, this);
        }
    }

    public int getImageHeight () {
        return (int) (image.getHeight(null) * ratio);
    }
}
```